# Redshift - Choosing DistKey

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Is it possible to use 2 dist keys in a table?

I have a query which makes use of 3 tables.

`Table 1 - Table 2 join on ID1` and `Table 2 - Table 3 join on ID2`.

I need to display the most recent data in this case.

So, according to my analysis `sortkey` can be `updated_time` since I'd be limiting data on the basis of this field.

Further, `dist key` should the attribute which would be most used for `joins`.

That means, for Table 1 `distkey` can be `ID1`, for Table 3 `distkey` can be ID2.

Can there be 2 distkeys for table 2 - ID1 and ID2?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is *not* possible to specify multiple DISTKEYs.

From [CREATE TABLE - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_TABLE_NEW.html):

> `DISTKEY`
> Keyword that specifies that the column is the distribution key for the table. **Only one column in a table can be the distribution key.**

The distribution key is used to distribute rows amongst servers. Preferably, when JOINing tables, they should have the same `DISTKEY` so that data is co-located on the same server and does not need to be sent between servers.

You will need to optimize for your *most important* table. It is not always possible to optimize for all tables and queries.

It is also possible to specify an `AUTO` distribution style. From [Distribution styles - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_choosing_dist_sort.html):

> With AUTO distribution, Amazon Redshift assigns an **optimal distribution style** based on the size of the table data. For example, Amazon Redshift initially assigns ALL distribution to a small table, then changes to EVEN distribution when the table grows larger. When a table is changed from ALL to EVEN distribution, storage utilization might change slightly. The change in distribution occurs in the background, in a few seconds.
>
> When you set DISTSTYLE to AUTO, Amazon Redshift might change the distribution of your table data to have a KEY-based distribution style.

I recommend studying [Tuning query performance - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c-optimizing-query-performance.html) and watching some [AWS Reinvent videos about Redshift](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=redshift+reinvent+performance) to discover how to best optimize tables and queries.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to John R's correct answer.

You should consider making either table 2 or table 3 DISTSTYLE ALL.  You don't mention sizes or other use patterns for these tables so this isn't a slam dunk.  It looks like these tables are likely dimensional in nature and the space increase for DISTSTYLE ALL is often minor or even a net win when dealing with smaller tables.